# No codesigning identities

Tags: ios, xcode

No codesigning identities (i.e. certificate and private key pairs) that match the provisioning profile specified in your build settings (“Ios7ProvisioningProfile”) were found.  Xcode can resolve this issue by downloading a new provisioning profile from the Member Center.

I used to upload application just fine.

Yet now when I tried to archieve the application. I got this message. I tried the automated fix but it doesn't work.

Basically it says XCode can resolve this issue. Yet I click fix button and it doesn't work.

Where in my build settings my profile is listed?

Comment: do you have multiple development machines that you work with?

Answer (score 1):

In build settings, select All options instead of basics. There you will find a section called code-signing, All provisioning options are listed there. If you wish to see all the provisioning profiles installed on your system, you could use iPhone Configuration Utility.